# How to temporary store a record in a postgresql function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a table where I have a list of cities and unique codes assigned to them (city_code_table).

I also have a table where I have the list of street names and the code of the cities (street_table).

I would like to create a function where the input is the name of a city, and it creates a table with the streets in that city.

The function would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_1(city_name text)
RETURNS VOID AS
$body$
BEGIN
!!!MISSING PART!!!
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE '||quote_ident(city_name)||'_streets AS
            SELECT * from street_table where city_code = temporary_variable;'
    RETURN;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpqsql;
```

In the missing part I would like to somehow store a temporary_variable as the result of

```
SELECT city_code from city_code_table where city_name is 'Budapest';
```

I know it not works like that in this language, but I am 100% sure that the result of the latter code is always one record and not more.
I could insert this to the previous codes like this:

```
SELECT * from street_table where city_code = (SELECT city_code from city_code_table where city_name is 'Budapest');
```

I don't really want to to this, because in the full function I would use this code several times, so this solution would really slow down the process, in my opinion.
Also I know that it would be way more easier to do this if the street_table would have the city names as well, and not only the codes, but that's not me who decides this.

Thanks for any kind of help in advance!

Comment: Creating a table to return a simple join result seems like the wrong approach to begin with. But without more details it's hard to tell what a better approach would be. Maybe a VIEW between the two tables, or something similar

Comment: To me this sounds more like a [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). What is the actual underlying problem that function should solve?

Comment: You might be right. I tried to simplify my problem. The function would provide a tables filled with data as the result of selections and joins from several other tables, but the main point and the first step is that the input shoud be a city name, and from that I would like to determine the city code, based on the code table, because in every table in our database, only the city code is stored. That's why I wouldn't want to use the selection in every case.

Comment: Why not simply join the needed tables and return the result of that join directly? With the details given, duplicating data each time you call the function seems the wrong approach (and **at least** it should be a temporary table rather than a permanent). I still think you should create a VIEW that brings those two tables together and get rid of the function altogether and then query the view

Comment: I will try it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The whole approach seems wrong to me, but anyway: you can use the complete SELECT statement in your CREATE TABLE statement.

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE '||quote_ident(city_name)||'_streets AS
         SELECT * 
         from street_table 
         where city_code in (select city_code 
                             from city_code_table 
                             where city_name = $1)'
     USING city_name;
```

The `USING` part will pass the value of the function parameter to the parameter placeholder `$1`